# How to change html href attribute variable value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change html href attribute variable value ?post=55 to ?post=44 with button click while not changing other URL variable(thread=7) using jQuery, but don't know how.

**HTML**

```
<button class="button">button</button>

<a href="posts.php?thread=7&post=55" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {

$("a").attr('href','posts.php?post=44') // this does not work because it removes ?thread=7
$("a").attr('href','posts.php?thread=7&post=44') // this also does not work because ?thread=7 is just a placeholder. I don't know what actual thread number is going to be.
  
});
```

**This is what I have**

```
<a href="posts.php?thread=7&post=55" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

**This is what I want when clicking button**

```
<a href="posts.php?thread=7&post=44" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

Comment: I think the only way would be to read the href value and construct a new one based on the existing params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can provide a function to `prop()` (note: not `attr()`*) which accepts the current attribute value as an argument. From there you can use a regular expression to find the number within the current `href` and replace it.

The benefit of using this method is that it will work no matter where in the URL the `post` argument appears.

Also in the following example I stored the page value to set as a `data` attribute on the `button`, but this can be amended to suit your specific use case.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('a').prop('href', (i, href) => href.replace(/(post=)\d{1,2}/, '$1' + $(this).data('page')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-page="44">Update post to '44'</button>

<a href="posts.php?thread=7&post=55" class="post-link">Post</a>
```

`*` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/519413) for why you should use `prop()` over `attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
   // Get the href Value:
   const link = $("a").attr('href'); // posts.php?thread=7&post=44
   // Split the href value by '&' (returns Array):
   const parts = link.split('&'); // ['posts.php?thread=7','post=44']
   // Get the actual post value (may not needed?)
   const post = parts.slice(-1)[0]; // post=44
   // remove the 'post=44' part:
   parts.pop() // ['posts.php?thread=7']
   // Important if more than one "&" in URL:
   const linkBase = parts.join('&');
   // Build the new URL including YOUR Post number:
   const newUrl = linkBase + '&post=n';
   
   $("a").attr('href', newUrl)

// Sources:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
  
});
```

Please note that this is an example that can be improved but its written with all necessary steps to better followup.

Hope it helps